# DOMdocument - i want to put link to all img tags - See my code

Tags: php, drupal, domdocument

I want to add href to all img tags on my drupal post. My bellow code is working fine on html page but on drupal doesn't work(do not do anything):
Code:

```
 <?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->load($node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($images as $img) {
            $link = $doc->createElement('a');
            $link->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.example.com');
            $img->parentNode->insertBefore($link, $img);
            $link->appendChild($img);
        }
        echo $doc->saveHTML();
 ?>
```

what could be wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: what does `$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` contain?

Comment: contain drupal nodes

Comment: drupal nodes? as in a string of nodes? or a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` contains a string of nodes, then you're using the wrong function. Use `$doc->loadHTML()` instead:

```
$doc->loadHTML($node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
```

`->load()` loads the file. You feed it with a path, not a node string.